# Can someone help me find why I'm getting an unexpected , expecting ;?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, as I can't see anything wrong with my eyes.

In NetBeans on Line 9 I'm getting "Expected , but found ;"

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".scroll").click(function(event){event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},500);
    });
    $("#accordion".accordion({
        collapsible:true,
        active:false,
        heightStyle:"content"
    });
    $("#menu-mobile img").click(function(){
        $('nav ul.menu').toggleClass("show");
    });
    $("#signup").click(function(){
        $(".members-form-wrapper#new-user").slideDown("slow");
    });
    $('#postcode').on('change',function(event){if(inputHasContent($(this))){
            $('.details').show();
        }else{
            $('.details').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I'm trying desperately to minify the load time on my wordpress install and encountering errors when i try to improve.

Something just tells me, that this is something really simple... but I just can't see it. Any help appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: How is this Off Topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgot to close brackets in the 5th line.

Change

```
 $("#accordion".accordion({
        collapsible:true,
        active:false,
        heightStyle:"content"
    });
```

to

```
 $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible:true,
        active:false,
        heightStyle:"content"
    });
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple! If you don't mind me asking, did you use any tools.. or do you just use a logical approach and proof-read slowly?

Comment: @LeeCollings )) Nope, I didn't use any tools. I just read your code carefully.

Comment: @LeeCollings, see [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code) for tools, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to close '#accordion' braces

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible:true,
        active:false,
        heightStyle:"content"
    });
```